# Видимость родительского элемента

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify

Предположим, у меня есть тройная вложенность элементов. v-content, внутри v-dialog, на нем v-btn. Есть ли какая то возможность сделать так, что бы в зависимости от значения какого-то либо свойства v-dialog либо отображался, либо нет. Т.е. v-btn был бы виден либо на v-dialog, либо сразу на v-content?

```
<v-content>
  <v-dialog :value=true гипотетическое_свойство="false">
    <v-btn>ok</v-btn>
  </v-dialog>
</v-content>
```

Было бы идентично:

```
<v-content>
  <v-btn>ok</v-btn>
</v-content>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вряд ли. Лучше как-то переверстать без вложенности v-btn в v-dialog